# Autoscaling y axis in interactive matplotlib plot (with slider)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, slider, jupyter

I have the following code, which lets me interactively change a function in jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

# Define stuff
my_func = lambda x, c: x - c

# Make plot
x = np.arange(0, 50, 1)
c_init = 10
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, my_func(x, c_init), lw=2)

# adjust the main plot to make room for the sliders
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

# Make a vertically oriented slider to control the stock volume
ax_c = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.25, 0.0225, 0.63])
c_slider = Slider(
    ax=ax_c,
    label="My function",
    valmin=-100,
    valmax=100,
    valinit=c_init,
    orientation="vertical"
)

# The function to be called anytime a slider's value changes
def update(val):
    line.set_ydata(my_func(x, c_slider.val))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    
# register the update function with each slider
c_slider.on_changed(update)

# Create a `matplotlib.widgets.Button` to reset the sliders to initial values.
resetax = fig.add_axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    c_slider.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```

While it works nicely, the y axis is not scaled properly as I am changing the constant. I tried to fix this using `ax.autoscale()`, `fig.autoscale()` and a bunch of other stuff within the update function, but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your `ylim` on the `ax` object when you're sliding, so that means inside of the `update` function.

#### Simple solution

```
def update(val):
    new_ydata = my_func(x, c_slider.val)
    line.set_ydata(new_ydata)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    ax.set_ylim([min(new_ydata), max(new_ydata)])
```

As you see, we define a new variable called `new_ydata` which we use to set the ydata, but we also use it in the `set_ylim()` function to determine what the new y axis limits are.

Although it works, it is not very nice. Having your limits be exactly equal to a data point is not very visually appealing. For this problem, we can introduce a margin that we can easily calculate.

#### Adding a margin to our plot

```
def update(val):
    new_ydata = my_func(x, c_slider.val)
    line.set_ydata(new_ydata)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    relative_margin = 0.05
    min_new_y = min(new_ydata)
    max_new_y = max(new_ydata)
    margin = (max_new_y - min_new_y)*relative_margin
    ax.set_ylim([min_new_y - margin, max_new_y + margin])
```

As you see, we do the same as before, but we introduce a margin. We use the `relative_margin` value as a proportion of the magnitude of the data, so that you always have a nice margin that scales together with your data.

Hope this helps!